# Vue Router - Changing to history mode in an existing application and handling old bookmarks

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, bookmarks

I have an application that was not using 'history' mode in vue router settings. So all the existing URLs have a '/#/'. Example - `~/#/login` or `~/#/page1`

When I add the mode: 'history', the new urls work great.
However if I try an old bookmark that still has '#', the routing fails.

Do I have to use router.replace to strip off the '#' or is there a better way of doing this?

I looked through a number of solutions but none (that I checked) talk about this scenario where  I am switching to 'history' mode for an existing application

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-history-mode-with-support-for-legacy-hash-mode-urls/38073

Comment: Thanks Phil. I used hash value instead of fullPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case all new pages have been introduced after setting history mode (the condition `&& to.name !== 'newPage'` is very specific to my case), so the solution that does work for me is

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const redirectPath = to.hash.split('#')[1]
  if (to.hash && to.name !== 'newPage') {
    next({
      path: redirectPath,
      hash: '',
      replace: true
    })
  }

...
return next()
}
```

In this case, if I use my old bookmark (say ~/#/page1) the to.hash holds the value '#/page1', so all am doing is splitting the hash to ["", "/page1"] and then setting path in next() to '/path1' with replace being set to true. Works for me.